# Multiple NVD3 charts on page. How to simplify the javascript code and wrap function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am currently using NVD3 on website to graph charts with one of the pages having 6 charts. I have currently just add 6 functions for each the six graphs but I feel that this is not the most elegant way of approaching the problem. Below is an example of the relevant html/javascript code:

```
<div id="chicago" class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions chart'>
  <svg> </svg>
</div>

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chicago = nv.models.lineChart()
      .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 80})
      .x(function(d,i) { return i })
      .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  chicago.transitionDuration(500);

  chicago.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {

      var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
      if (dx > 0) {
          return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
      }
      return null;
  });

  chicago.yAxis
      .axisLabel('Price ($/Dth)')
      .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',.2f')(d) });

  nv.log(testdata);
  d3.select('#chicago svg')
      .datum(testdata)
      .call(chicago);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chicago.update);

  return chicago;
});
```

How would I wrap that function so I can reuse it multiple times without have to repeat it and replace the name (in this case 'chicago') for every graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite simple, this is one way of doing it.

**HTML :**

```
<div id='chart1'>
    <h3>My Chart 1</h3>
    <svg></svg>
</div>
<div id='chart2'>
    <h3>My Chart 2</h3>
    <svg></svg>
</div>
<div id='chart3'>
    <h3>My Chart 3</h3>
    <svg></svg>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
// Call my charts , pass in my div id here
drawChart('chart1');
drawChart('chart2');
drawChart('chart3');

//Donut chart example
function drawChart(div) {
    var width = height = 400;
    
    nv.addGraph(function () {
        var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
            .x(function (d) {
            return d.label
        }).y(function (d) {
            return d.value
        }).width(width)
          .height(height)
          .showLabels(true)
          .labelThreshold(.05)
          .labelType("percent")
          .donut(true);

        d3.select("#" + div + " svg")
            .datum(exampleData())
            .attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
            .transition().duration(350)
            .call(chart);

        return chart;
    });
}
```

Here is a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/p6yn8m1u/) of it.